# how to integrate G722 codec for my pjsip application in ios

Tags: ios, voip

I am developing an application for VOIP.I had integrated pjsip into my application through cocoapods and i am able to call from my ios app to android,but there shows an error codec incompatible,So i want to integrate g722 codec for my application bcz in android they are using g722 codec.

So can any one tell me the procedure for how to integrate G722 codec.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: g722 codec was added by default in pjsip

Answer (score 2):

G722 codec is available by default in PJSIP. You can make sure that it is enabled in your code by adding the following lines:

```
        const pj_str_t *ilbc = pj_cstr(&tmp, "G722/16000/1");
        pjsua_codec_set_priority(ilbc, (pj_uint8_t)PJMEDIA_CODEC_PRIO_NORMAL);
```

In case the codec is missing, you can follow this guide to integrate a codec: http://saravnandm.blogspot.com/2016/07/pjsip-25-g729-codec.html